# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.parser.Parser

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using dependency
org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3
 to parse html String, and it was working fine until i added Firebase Database dependency to my gradle file. After adding the Firebase database library 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-d`enter code here`atabase:10.0.1'
i got the following error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.parser.Parser"

The error occurs when i run my project on a 18 API device, but it runs with no errors when i run on a 25 API device.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: same problem exists for me too.Did you get any solution for this??

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue, i am getting same issue.